# Creating content regarding to node address arguments

Tags: nodes, caching, path-aliases, uri

Say it I have such node alias:
**example.com/content/my-fancy-page/**

If user enters to node above, he will see default page content of my fancy page.
After some process I will redirect him to this:
**example.com/content/my-fancy-page/tt3741/**
or this
**example.com/content/my-fancy-page/tt3802/**

1. Regarding to user's selection he will see the "tt3741" or "tt3802" content that resides inside database. Is it possible to do this with hooking etc. When I try "example.com/content/some-old-page/foobar" in my old website I get 404 error. So is it nt possible?
2. Is it possible to cache these three addresses seperately with Boost module? Or Boost only caches "/my-fancy-page/"

Comment: How do you redirect users? What is exactly tt341, or tt3802?

Comment: I give them some options inside an HTML form. If user selects option 1, I redirect him to tt341, if he selects ooption 2 I redirect to tt3802. Say it he selected option 1. Inside "tt341" page I have two options again. Regarding to answer, user will be sent to another page.

Comment: Are tt3802, and tt341 path aliases? May you show the code you are using to redirect users (JavaScript, or PHP code)?

Comment: Thank you for your interest.. They can be path aliases or not. I didn't write any code for this feature. I'm just trying to design the structure.. Constraints are like this: - Every node has its own sub nodes - Sub nodes will have a string code inside URL, so I will get relevant data from database - Pages will be cached by boost.

Comment: I was wondering about your, "Because now it gives a 404 error." I thought you already wrote code, and you were wondering why it didn't work. If that were the case, it would be better to show the code.

Comment: Sorry for confusion. I have a website already, and I wanted to try whether argument adding gives the same page or not. I tried for "/content/my-old-page/tryme" and it gave 404 error, while "/content/my-old-page/" exists..

Answer (score 0):

Path aliases must be exact, thus if you want `my-fancy-page/tt3741` to work you need to create an alias for it. If you link to the node path `node/6` then `node/6/tt341` will work. This has to do with how [hook_menu](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_menu/7) works vs how [path aliases work](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!path.inc/function/drupal_path_initialize/7).

If you wish to hack around how path aliases work you can try out the PURL's Path Extensions feature http://drupal.org/project/purl or use [hook_url_inbound_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_url_inbound_alter/7) to get the correct node given the unique alias.

Boost will work as long as each URL is unique (same as drupal's core cache). Good luck.